# how to get postal code using reverse geocoding in android

Tags: android, geocoding

I am new to Andriod development..i try to get postal code and city name from reverse geocoding using below code.it finding latitude, longitude value fine but cant able to get cityname and postal code.

```
package com.example.code;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LbsGeocodingActivity extends Activity {

private static final long MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1; // in Meters
private static final long MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 1000; // in Milliseconds

protected LocationManager locationManager;

protected Button retrieveLocationButton;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    retrieveLocationButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.retrieve_location_button);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
            MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES,
            MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,
            new MyLocationListener()
    );

retrieveLocationButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showCurrentLocation();
        }
});       

}   

protected void showCurrentLocation() {

    Location location =    locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    Geocoder gcoder=new Geocoder(this, Locale.ENGLISH);
    List<Address> Data = null;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
    if (location != null) {

        latitude=location.getLatitude();
        longitude=location.getLongitude();

        try {
            Data=gcoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String cityname=Data.get(0).getLocality();
        String postalcode=Data.get(0).getPostalCode();

        String message=String.format("City Name \n PostalCode \n",  Data.get(0).getLocality(),Data.get(0).getPostalCode());
        Toast.makeText(LbsGeocodingActivity.this,message ,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}  

private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        String message = String.format(
                "New Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",
                location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude()
        );
        Toast.makeText(LbsGeocodingActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle b) {
        Toast.makeText(LbsGeocodingActivity.this, "Provider status changed",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
        Toast.makeText(LbsGeocodingActivity.this,
                "Provider disabled by the user. GPS turned off",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
        Toast.makeText(LbsGeocodingActivity.this,
                "Provider enabled by the user. GPS turned on",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();          }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code for finding the city and zipcode is right, but your code for formatting the string for your toast is wrong. It does not put the values in there.

It should look like this:

```
String message=String.format("City Name %s \n PostalCode %d \n",  Data.get(0).getLocality(),Data.get(0).getPostalCode());
```

The %s represents a string and the %s represents a decimal number (integer).

Comment: Thanks for replying for my doubt dear friend,i tried your code in my application but its shows application code stopped unexpectedly .please can u help me ...

Comment: I'm sorry. The postal code should be a string too. So %s instead of %d. I'll fix my response.